# How do you get grouped product associated items to show in the search results page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to quickly preview names of all the associated items- similar to this:

[image]

Trying edit the list.phtml file but everything I do makes the entire search result body disappear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this inside of the product collection loop in list.phtml. I sincerely hope you are not editing core files but rather making your own module or custom template though :-)

You can test this out in `catalog/product/list.phtml`

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED): ?>
    <?php $associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product); ?>
    <?php foreach($associatedProducts as $associatedProduct): ?>
        <?php echo $this->__($associatedProduct->getName()); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, if the results of your search body are disappearing, you most likely have an error but your error reporting is not turned on. If this is a dev site, go to index.php and uncomment the line that has `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and that will allow your errors to display on screen.

If it is a production site, go to System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings and turn on logging. Errors will appear in `var/log/exception.log` or `var/log/system.log`

Comment: @jburcher its my pleasure! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted and good luck in your endeavors!